# Mapbox satellite failed to upload in QGIS

Tags: qgis, mapbox, quickmapservices, nextgis

I tried to upload the mapbox satellite map in QGIS and got this message: QuickMapServices: Failed to download all 16 files. Mapbox

[image]

I have reinstalled the QuickMapServices plugin, but it did not fix this problem. I tried to use the [Mapbox online](https://www.mapbox.com/help/mapbox-arcgis-qgis/) help menu, but I think it is not updated and the instructions were ineffective.
The other Mapbox map I have in QGIS,"Mapbox Gray", is working just fine.

[image]

What can I do in order to fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @HDunn says, it looks like that API Key has been revoked. It looks like you'll need to apply for an API key of your own.

It's possible to change the TMS urls in the QuickMapServices plugin, so you should be able to set things up if you get your own key. I've not tried this myself, so not sure if it works, but here's a screenshot :-

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I'm pretty sure the TMS that the plugin is calling is broken, either the token was cancelled, ran out of request capacity, or blocked by MapBox.
  [image]

Try using a different satellite image background, either from the QMS plugin, or external. 
You can also [follow NextGIS' FAQ](https://qms.nextgis.com/faq#fix) regarding broken services